# How I can express this expression in function o k?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I´m trying to find how the author have reached to the result of this expression at the right side.

Sincerely I don´t know how He manipulate that.  So, anyone may help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$kA\frac{(T-T_0)}{l_1+l_2+l_3} = A\frac{(T-T_0)}{\frac{l_1}{k_1}+\frac{l_2}{k_2}+\frac{l_3}{k_3}} \iff k = \underbrace{\left(A\frac{(T-T_0)}{l_1+l_2+l_3}\right)^{-1}}_{= \frac{1}{A}\frac{l_1+l_2+l_3}{(T-T_0)}} A\frac{(T-T_0)}{\frac{l_1}{k_1}+\frac{l_2}{k_2}+\frac{l_3}{k_3}} = \frac{A}{A}\frac{(T-T_0)}{(T-T_0)} \frac{l_1+l_2+l_3}{\frac{l_1}{k_1}+\frac{l_2}{k_2}+\frac{l_2}{k_3}}=\frac{l_1+l_2+l_3}{\frac{l_1}{k_1}+\frac{l_2}{k_2}+\frac{l_2}{k_3}} $$

Comment: Where may I find a book where there is some exercices like that?

Answer (score 2):

Take the equation just before the $\implies$ and multiply both sides by $\frac {l_1+l_2+l_3}{A(T-T_0)}$